# Kind of a funny slide

Tags: grammar

It's kind of a funny slide.

Is this correct to say? I guess "a kind of funny slide" doesn't make sense either, but "a" after "kind of" seems a little uncomfortale to me.

Comment: Do you really mean "funny", or do you mean a "fun slide"? Also, some more details might be helpful because the two are possible options, but they mean different things. Oh, I forgot to include, do you mean a like one you would find in the park? Or a slide as in a photo slide.

Comment: Slide, as in Powerpoint or slide, as in, slip-sliding away?

Comment: Playground slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's kind of a" or "It's kind of an" are commonly used English phrases used to indicate that "it" falls roughly, but not exactly into a category, group, or type of things; in this case the category of "funny slides". If the words "kind of" in the sentence were replaced with "is" or "precisely", the statement would indicate a closer or exact match with the category.

Other examples of this phrase and similar others include:

```
It's kind of an unusual situation.
It's sort of a special circumstance.
It's really a comfortable chair.
```

In every case, the "a" or "an" before the thing being described, as well as the "It's" (it is) at the sentence beginning indicate the singularity of the described object. If you wished to indicate more than one, the sentence might replace "It is" with "They are" and "a" with "some", "many", "several", or some other word that indicates more than one. Your example sentence might become:

```
"They are kind of funny slides"
```

In this case, the "a" is no longer needed since there is more than one slide.

Answer (score 0):

> It's **kind of** a funny slide.

[kind of](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind-of) without an article is an interjection which is *used when you are trying to explain or describe something, but you cannot be exact*. It is also used as a [discourse particle, filler, hedge, or speech disfluency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker). Much to the irritation of adults, young people use the word **like** extensively in the same way.

> It's **a kind of** funny slide

The meaning of [kind](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind) when used with an article is *a particular type*.

A similar sentence might be

> An apple is **a kind of** fruit.

Comment: Yep. Let's blame the horrible rules of English on the kids. After all, it was perfect before they got ahold of it, in spite of what our parents might claim.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkRipley, In my experience, it's something that kids grow out of as they become more articulate: they in turn cringe when the next generation does exactly the same thing.